# Flask-SQLAlchemy resourceclosederror

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, pymssql

I have the following project structure
- app
---> settings.py
---> **init**.py
- models
---> **init**.py
---> config.py
- module1
---> **init**.py
---> utils.py

```
[app]
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://....'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    "db01": 'mssql://...'
    "db02": 'mssql://...'
}
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT = 60  

[__init__.py]
..
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
..
app = Flask("myapp")
app.config.from_object('app.settings')

sql = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    pass

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    return response

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    sql.session.remove()

[model]
[config.py]
from app import sql

class Sample(sql.model):
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    __bind__ = "db01"
    id = sql.Column("Id",sql.Integer,primary_key = True)
    value = sql.Column("Value",sql.String)  
[module1]  
[utils.py]  
from app import sql  
from model import Sample  

data = sql.session.query(Sample).all()
```

The issue I am facing is that I frequently encounter a "ResourceClosedError"

From what I understand about the error, flask attempts to use a connection that it thinks is ok but has been closed by the database. Is there a way to explicitly instruct flask to use a new connection each time a request is issued, or even better to check if the connection is alive and if not open a new one?
Also note that the webserver used is gunicorn and not Flask's

Comment: I think you don't need to explicitly close the session yourself. `flask-sqlalchemy` takes care of that.

Comment: That's true,However the issue I am facing is related to not opening a new session